# How to remove (.php/?ref=example.com) in php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To remove the `.php` in an URL I am using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So when I open any page of my site without php - e.g. `example.com/monitor/test` - my site is working fine.
But when I open my site via `example.com/monitor/test/?ref=example.com` I get an  error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

How can i solve this error?
`/test` means `/test.php` - I have removed `.php` using code in .htaccess

Comment: I had to edit this a lot because it was unreadable. I hope, the meaning didn't get lost. It was pretty hard to get it at all :) I guess we'll need the code where you are processing the '?ref='-part.

Comment: Ok thanks well  tell me how can i remove like as .php remove 
i want to open my link like this example.com/monitor/test when i open example.com/monitor/test/?ref=example.com

Answer (score 1):

Your url seems incorrect. 
It should be

```
  example.com/monitor/test?ref=example.com
```

Note that i removed the slash after **test** . I did this because the slash indicates that **test** is a folder and not a file. I'm not sure if this will solve the problem though. I suggest changing the title because your issue does not involve php. It is htaccess related.

Comment: my URL like this example.com/monitor/test.com/?ref=example.com or example.com/monitor/test.biz/?ref=example.com...i have created .php file for domain name that why i want to remove /?ref=example.com

Comment: you can say i have created .php file for my all domain name like this
example.com.php or example.bix.php....so i have remove .php using htaccess.so my reflink for my user that is /?ref=example.com